# Sets of Matrices All Infinite Products of Which Converge

Tags: grammar

This is the name of a quite famous mathematical paper by Daubechies and Lagarias.

Could someone explain to me the grammar of this title? For me (German speaker) the title sounds totally awkward.

My question is not about the papers mathematics.

Comment: There's nothing "awkward" -- it is technically the most appropriate phrasing as required in the context.

Comment: @Kris Very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the grammar is awkward.

*Which* is a pronoun, and in expressions like this, you can figure out what the expression involving it means by replacing *which* with its antecedent. (This doesn't work for all expressions involving *of which*.)

An example from the OED:

> They wrote concerning things the thought of which set their hearts on fire.

What do we get when we replace *which* with its antecedent? — *The thought of these things set their hearts on fire.*

Let's do that here. We are considering a set of matrices such that

> all infinite products of this set of matrices converge.

What is an infinite product of a set of matrices? This is grammatically ambiguous, but here what is meant is an infinite product all of whose terms belong to the set.

Having only had two years of German in high school and college, I can't tell where the difference with German grammar lies.

Playing with Google translate a little, I think what seems awkward is the placement of the *of which*. Google translate gives:

> Sie schrieben über Dinge, deren Gedanken ihre Herzen in Brand setzten.
>   They wrote concerning things of which the thought their hearts on fire set.

Are both placements of *of which* are grammatical in English? (Moving the verb to the end isn't, of course.) I don't know. I can only find a few uses of *of which the thought* online, and the word order sounds old-fashioned to me. The standard word order is, and seems to have always been, *the thought of which*.

Comment: -1 Please see my comment at OP.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we can consider it as being short for:

*This paper describes Sets of Matrices for which All Infinite Products Converge*

In other words, all infinite products (of the sets of matrices described) converge. Or, more accurately, the sets of matrices (being discussed) are defined by being the ones where all infinite products converge.

The original might be clearer with a comma: *Sets of Matrices, All Infinite Products of Which Converge*

(I'm not sure the grammar is "awkward", but it is a bit cryptic. Like newspaper headlines.)

Comment: I think "of which",  as in the question and your second suggestion, would be better in the first.  It *probably* makes no difference...